# How to write the type annotation of class method React.Component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to reuse the type annotation of a `React.Component`'s class method at multiple places. For that reason I would like to extract the type annotation of  class methods and create (and export) them as separate type. In the example below (the `handleClick()` class method):

```tsx
export type Amount: number;
interface State {
    amount: Amount;
}

class Example extends React.Component<{}, State> {
    handleClick(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        // some code
    }
    render() {
        <AnotherComponent
            amount={this.state.amount}
            handleClick={this.state.handleClick}
        />
    }
}
```

it's type annotation should be extracted to:

```tsx
export type HandleClickType = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
```

I thought I could just easily place that type back like:

```tsx
class Example extends React.Component<{}, State> {
    handleClick : HandleClickType (e) {}
}
```

How can I do this? The reason I want to do this, is to prevent code duplication when I pass a function as props and have to retype the type annotation.

Would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this but the function will be a field not a method, there are subtle differences.

First the solution. Your function type is ok, but the way you initialize the field is not ok:

```
class Example extends React.Component<{}, State> {
    handleClick:HandleClickType = (e) => {
        this // is Example
    }

    handleClickFunction:HandleClickType = function(e) {
        this // this is any and might cause an error depending on compiler settings
    }
}
```

The first field is initialized to an arrow function and thus captures `this` from the class context and accessing `this` will work as expected. The second example uses a regular function which will have `this` typed as `any` which will mean that under `noImplcitThis` accessing it will actually cause an error (and without this option accessing `this` will be unchecked as it is of type any)

We can get around this issue by either using an explicit annotation or adding an extra parameter to the function type to help with the inference of `this` inside the function

```
export type HandleClickType = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
export type HandleClickTypeWithThis<T> = ( this: T, e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
class Example extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  handleClickFunctionWithInfferedThis: HandleClickTypeWithThis<this> = function (e) {
    this // this is now example
  }
  handleClickFunctionWithExplcitThis: HandleClickType = function (this: Example, e) {
    this // this is now example
  }
}
```

I mention the `function` options for completeness, if you are unsure an arrow function will probably work best.

Now about the subtle difference between method and function filed. Beside different icon code completion will use for the two, the big difference is that the method is allocated once and assigned to the prototype while with the field the closure will be created and assigned to the instance for each object. This will lead to more memory usage which might matter in certain scenarios. But if you need to capture `this` anyway it will not matter much as you will alocate a new closure anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer!